# How can I make a screenshot (printscreen) on my Macbook Pro using Windows 7?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, screen-capture

How can I make a screenshot on Macbook pro using Windows 7?
The keyboard does not include a special key for this function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using Bootcamp, Apple has provided [documentation of key mappings](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1220):

> <kbd>print screen</kbd> = <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Your best option would be to use the snipping tool that comes with Windows 7.

Comment: Snipping Tool is available only in the Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate, and Enterprise editions of Windows 7. If @user1007241 has a different version of Windows, they will not have this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Like Davo says, use the *on screen* keyboard when you can not use or remember the key combo.

Start -> Accessories -> Accessibilty -> On screen keyboard. Then slide it mostly out of the way while you can still click the print screen key with your mouse pointer. Edit away the on screen keyboard from the shot later if you want to.

Answer (score -3):

Try using the on screen keyboard and hitting the prt scrn button

Comment: You know that a macbook has no prt scrn button?

Comment: You know he said *on screen* keyboard? It's a program, not the device keyboard. Worked nicely. Start "Onboard", hit the button marked "123", then the "Prnt" button. Even works for capturing a specific window - just focus that window, then do as above, but hold "Alt" on your real keyboard while you hit "Prnt" on the virtual one.